# Using ASM 4.0 how could I create a simple Getter?

Tags: java, bytecode, getter, java-bytecode-asm

Say I had a class like this:

```
public class Example{

     private String secret = "Secret String";

}
```

How would I be able to add a getter to return this string (No reflection to be used), so I'd like to add this somehow

```
public String getSecret(){
    return secret;
}
```

Comment: Why not just compile a test class (like the above) and examine the bytecode?

Comment: Do you have anything completed as far as injection goes? (i.e a method of accessing class bytes, an instrumentation implementation, etc)

Comment: @Ancurio ASM (and other bytecode engineering libraries) are most often intended for use *at runtime*, modifying classes just before they are loaded.

Comment: I have a ClassReader and ClassWriter object to examine + interact with the class, but I have no idea where to go from there.  The documentation for ASM isn't very promising.

Comment: @Vulcan oh, I didn't know.. so it's like a libFFI for Java?

Comment: @Ancurio No worries; I actually don't know what libFFI is, I've only really ever programmed in Java and PHP. Steinburg, My apologies for not replying earlier, but I haven't used ASM before, only BCEL (it's slower twin).

Answer (score 6):

Straight from the ASM FAQ: "[How do I generate Setters and Getters for my class?](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q9)".

Also see "[How do I generate {some Java code} with ASM?](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q11)"